# Unable to undelete the child

Tags: master-detail, delete, undelete

I have to objects (Kampagne and Schedule)

The relation between Kampagne and Schedule is "Master-Details" where the Kampagne is the Master and the schedules are the details.

My problem is:

I deleted the schedule,the kampagne (in this order) and then I undeleted the kampagne and the Schedule.

Only the kampagne was fully restored, for the schedule i am getting this error message:

```
System.DmlException: Undelete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a1p4E000002t8LAQAY; first error: UNDELETE_FAILED, Entity is not in the recycle bin: []
```

How could I undelete the Child if i already undeleted the Father ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, you can't.

[Considerations for Relationships](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm)

> Deleting a detail record moves it to the Recycle Bin and leaves the master record intact; deleting a master record also deletes related detail and subdetail records. Undeleting a detail record restores it, and undeleting a master record also undeletes related detail and subdetail records. However, **if you delete a detail record and later, separately, delete its master record, you cannot undelete the detail record, as it no longer has a master record to relate to.**

Emphasis added by me.

Comment: Thx, i got my answer ;)